How to say "this"
I have to make a video in German explaining Wechselpräpositionen. My first two lines are: An, auf, hinter, in, neben, über, unter, vor und zwischen. ___ sind die Wechselpräpositionen.
I want to say "these are the german two-way prepositions" but google translate is giving me various different answers on what word to use for "these". What word would fit best?

"These are the german two-way prepositions." gives how many different answers?

Der Inhalt der Vorschläge wäre auch interessant.

It's Das.

Heckel und Jeckel. Das sind die beiden Krähen aus den Looney Tunes.

It must be neuter singular because your sentence refers back to the list of Wechselpräpositionen as a single item. And it should be a plain das and not dies because you don't post this list to contradict a different list.
